# What is LinkedHashMap and what is it used for?

Tags: java, android, listview, linkedhashmap

When I was going through a example code which has ListViews I came up with `LinkedHashMap`.
What is a `LinkedHashMap` and where can we use it and how? I went through several articles but did not understand fully. Is it necessary when creating `ListView`. What is the connection between ListViews and LinkedHashMaps?  Thank you.

Comment: We can tell you, but it's always better when you read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: this one as well [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Simplicity, let us understand what is the difference between **HashMap** and **LinkedHashMap**.

**HashMap**: It gives output in Random orders means there is no proper sequence how we have inserted values.

whereas

**LinkedHashMap**: It gives output in sequential order.

Let us see a small example: with HashMap

```
    // suppose we have written a program
    .
    .
    // now use HashMap
    HashMap map = new HashMap();  // create object
    map.put(1,"Rohit");          // insert values
    map.put(2,"Rahul");
    map.put(3,"Ajay");

    System.out.println("MAP=" +map); //print the output using concatenation


    //So the output may be in any order like we can say the output may be as:
    Map={3=Ajay,2=Rahul,1=Rohit}
```

but this is not the case in LinkedHashMap
Just replace the "HashMap" with "LinkedHashMap" in the above code
and see
it will display the output in Sequential order like 1=Rohit will be displayed first then the others in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The docs are here.  But its basically a HashMap that also has a linked list, so you can have a consistently ordered iteration through it.  Note that this means removals may be O(n) time because you need to remove it from both data structures.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap is hashmap. But it maintains order of insertion. But HashMap doesnt maintain order.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Linked Hash Map is a Map which stored key value pair,
Linked Hash Map add the values may very slow, But while retrieving the values is very easy.
For fast retrieval of values we could prefer Linked Hash Map.